# Loading a view routed by a URL parameter (e.g., /users/:id) in MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I am having difficulties with trying to load a user by their id, for some reason my http.get call isn't hitting my controller.

I get the following error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/users.js:10:8)
```

**Update**
I've fixed my code up as per comments below, but now my code just enters an infinite loop in the angular users controllers (see code below) and I do not get the error above.

I am using the [Angular Express Generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) for reference

**Backend - nodejs, express, mongo**

routes.js:

```
// not sure if this is required, but have used it before?
app.param('username', users.show);

app.route('/api/users/:username')
    .get(users.show);
```

controller.js:

```
// This never gets hit
exports.show = function (req, res, next, username) {
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    })
    .exec(function (err, user) {
        req.user = user;
        res.json(req.user || null);
    });
};
```

**Frontend - angular**

app.js:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/users/:username', {
        templateUrl: function( params ){ return 'users/view/' + params.username; },
        controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    })
```

services/user.js:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('User', function ($resource) {

        return $resource('/api/users/:username', {
            username: '@username'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {}
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    username:'username'
                }
            }
        });
});
```

controllers/users.js:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$route', 'User', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route, User) {

        // this returns the error above
        $http.get( '/api/users/' + $routeParams.username )
            .success(function( user ) {
                $scope.user = user;
            })
            .error(function( err) {
                console.log( err );
            });
}]);
```

If it helps, I'm using [this setup](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['User', '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', function ($scope,    $http, User, $route, $routeParams) {
```

you forgot to add $http in your users.js file

try this one

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['User', '$scope', '$http','$route', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, User, $route, $routeParams) {
```

Comment: Ah sorry, sure it was missing, but this doesn't necessarily have to be there, as long as it's passed as a parameter. I think writing them as strings before is strictly for minification purposes no? Either way, I've fixed up the code, sorry it was messy and old.

Comment: you are getting undefined error. Do you have a service called 'User' in your angular app?

Comment: Ok, I've fixed up my code, but now it just enters into an infinite loop inside the Users controller (see updated code above)

Comment: I've figured this out, will post an answer soon. You're right in the fact that my initial code was messy. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First we need to clean up your Inline Array Notation (Read -https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Based on this code

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['User', '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, User, $route, $routeParams) {

        // this returns the error above
        $http.get( '/api/users/' + $route.username ).success(function( user ) {
            $scope.user = user;
        });
}]);
```

Your $scope variable is actually some *User* service, your $http is actually your *$scope*, User is actually *$route*,  $route is *$routeParams*, and $routeParams is actually *$routeParams* if you aren't using a compiler. Change this to the following and tell me what you get:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'User', '$route', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, User, $route, $routeParams) {

        // this returns the error above
        $http.get( '/api/users/' + $route.username ).success(function( user ) {
            $scope.user = user;
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry I think I posted old code (it gets messy when trying to troubleshoot), I've cleaned it up

Comment: Ok, I've fixed up my code, but now it just enters into an infinite loop inside the Users controller (see updated code above)

Comment: Infinite loop? Weird. Does the page keep refreshing or what? In this loop, what so happening?

Comment: I've figured this out, will post an answer soon. You're right in the fact that my initial code was messy. Thanks for the help